# Best Way to mount Wald rear folding baskets to the rack on a Batavus Fryslan

Tags: cargo, rack

I just got these awesome [Wald rear folding baskets](http://waldsports.com/index.cfm/wald582rearfoldingbasket.html) as an early christmas present from my Girlfriend.  The hardware they came with will not fit on my [Batavus Fryslan](http://www.bikesfortherestofus.com/2010/12/batavus-fryslan.html) Rack.  What would be the best way to mount them?

Comment: Cable ties.  The cyclist's duct tape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this question, I got a twitter response from [my local bike shop](http://teabike.blogspot.com/) where I got my Batavus.  They suggested screw clamps, and I agreed it was the best choice and mounted my rack with them.  Urbanistic tea and bike is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRR83gxIdn0) really helped me with a milk crate mounting. Using the same concept with nylon string, I would expect you could attach your folding basket, only attaching to the non-moving portion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of baling wire and zip ties. I never rely on zip ties alone in a load bearing application. Zip ties will hold the basket tight and the baling wire will act as a failsafe. Use a load rated zip tie and inspect attachment points regularly. Replace zip ties as they break.

Alternatively you can probably find larger p clamps at your local hardware store that will fit your rack.

Comment: One hint on zip ties -- use colored ones, preferably black.  The pigment slows UV damage significantly vs the white/clear ones.